# SQL Query Joins (Create view of combined sum from different table)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Hi I need a help regarding this problem. I want to create a view where it displays the summary of purchased and sold items.

Theses are my tables:

```
**tblfruit**
 ID       Name
 1        Apple
 2        Orange
 3        mango


 **tblpurchaseditems**
ID      fruit_id        qty   amount
1         1             3      75
2         1             2      50
3         2             1      10
4         3             3      30

**tblsolditems**
ID      fruit_id        qty   amount
1         1             2      150
2         1             2      350
3         2             1      50
4         3             2      230
5         3             1      120
```

I want the output :

```
 **tblsummary**
ID      fruit_id        totalqtypurchased totalamountpurchased  totalqtysold  totalamountsold
1         1                 5                    125                4             500
2         2                 1                    10                 1             50
3         3                 3                    30                 3             350
```

Comment: do us a favor when you're asking for query advice and build as an SQL Fiddle set up with your table schema.  Otherwise we can't test the  queries we might suggest easily, which makes the barrier to assist rather high.  As the asker you should preemptively do as much work as you can to get your question answered effectively.

Comment: First off, normally purchased and sold are synonyms. Edit your question and show what you have tried. SO is **not** a code writing service. We're glad to help when you are stuck on a programming issue, but you have to at least try.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of ways of doing this, either online or using a join.

Inline:
Select name, (select sum(qty) from tableb) as totalqty
From tablea

Join:
Select a.name, sum(b.qty) as totalqty
From tablea a
Join tableb b
On b.itemid = a.itemid
Group by a.name

For multiple tables things can get trickier using joins due to duplication so inline queries can work better here, for smaller queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.fruit_id,sum(b.qty),sum(b.amount),sum(c.qty),sum(c.amount) 
from tblfruit a,tblpurchaseditems b,tblsolditems c 
where a.fruit_id=b.fruit_id and a.fruit_id=c.fruit_id
group by a.fruit_id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data and expected result

you can try to `UNION ALL` to combine `tblpurchaseditems` and `tblpurchaseditems` table and make `grp` to spite two result set. then use *condition aggregate function* to get your expect result.

```
CREATE TABLE tblpurchaseditems(
   ID INT,
   fruit_id INT,
   qty INT,
   amount INT
);

INSERT INTO tblpurchaseditems VALUES (1,1,3,75);
INSERT INTO tblpurchaseditems VALUES (2,1,2,50);
INSERT INTO tblpurchaseditems VALUES (3,2,1,10);
INSERT INTO tblpurchaseditems VALUES (4,3,3,30);

CREATE TABLE tblsolditems(
   ID INT,
   fruit_id INT,
   qty INT,
   amount INT
);


INSERT INTO tblsolditems VALUES (1,1,2,150);
INSERT INTO tblsolditems VALUES (2,1,2,350);
INSERT INTO tblsolditems VALUES (3,2,1,50);
INSERT INTO tblsolditems VALUES (4,3,2,230);
INSERT INTO tblsolditems VALUES (5,3,1,120);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT (@RN:=@RN+1) ID,
       fruit_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN  qty END) totalqtypurchased ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN  amount END) totalamountpurchased  ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grp = 2 THEN  qty END) totalqtysold,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grp = 2 THEN  amount END) totalamountsold
FROM (
  select 1 grp,fruit_id,qty,amount from tblpurchaseditems
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2,fruit_id,qty,amount FROM tblpurchaseditems
)t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0) v
GROUP BY fruit_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d8b3/2/0)**:

```
| ID | fruit_id | totalqtypurchased | totalamountpurchased | totalqtysold | totalamountsold |
|----|----------|-------------------|----------------------|--------------|-----------------|
|  1 |        1 |                 5 |                  125 |            5 |             125 |
|  2 |        2 |                 1 |                   10 |            1 |              10 |
|  3 |        3 |                 3 |                   30 |            3 |              30 |
```

**NOTE**

I would use a column `itemGroup` in table, which can represent which type.

- `1` mean `purchaseditems`
- `2` mean `solditems`

That would not need to use `UNION ALL` to combine two table, more make sense.

So in the table schema will look like.

```
CREATE TABLE tblitems(
       ID INT,
       fruit_id INT,
       qty INT,
       amount INT,
       itemGroup INT
);


INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (1,1,3,75,1);
INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (2,1,2,50,1);
INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (3,2,1,10,1);
INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (4,3,3,30,1);



INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (1,1,2,150,2);
INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (2,1,2,350,2);
INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (3,2,1,50 ,2);
INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (4,3,2,230,2);
INSERT INTO tblitems VALUES (5,3,1,120,2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT (@RN:=@RN+1) ID,
       fruit_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN  itemGroup = 1 THEN  qty END) totalqtypurchased ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN  itemGroup = 1 THEN  amount END) totalamountpurchased  ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN  itemGroup = 2 THEN  qty END) totalqtysold,
       SUM(CASE WHEN  itemGroup = 2 THEN  amount END) totalamountsold
FROM tblitems t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0) v
GROUP BY fruit_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d8b3/2/0)**:

```
| ID | fruit_id | totalqtypurchased | totalamountpurchased | totalqtysold | totalamountsold |
|----|----------|-------------------|----------------------|--------------|-----------------|
|  1 |        1 |                 5 |                  125 |            4 |             500 |
|  2 |        2 |                 1 |                   10 |            1 |              50 |
|  3 |        3 |                 3 |                   30 |            3 |             350 |
```